# Нужна помощь по устранению ошибки

Tags: html

Есть сайт соц сети, когда открываю с компа то всё ок, но когда открываю сайт с телефона то выдаёт ошибку " невозможно загрузить шаблон: index.tpl

Вот код index.tpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
{header}
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/badbrowser.php"></noscript>
<link media="screen" href="{theme}/port_style/do_91419945.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="{theme}/js/jquery.lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{theme}/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{theme}/js/reg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{theme}/js/likan_antv.js"></script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{theme}/images/fav.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<div class=bg>
 <div id=wrapper>
<img src="{theme}/images/top/logo.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network Logo">
<div id=centru>
<div id=left>
<h1 class=ru>Общайся,открывай для себя новое, делись, развлекайся </h1>
<h4>
</h4><br/> 
<a id="register" href="/register" rel="nofollow" title="Зарегистрируйся">Зарегистрируйся</a>
 </div>  </div>
 <form name="f_login" class="forma" action="#" method="post">
<div class="login-panel" id="err">
<input type="text" name="email" id="log_email" maxlength="50" placeholder="Электронная почта">
<input type="password" name="password" id="log_password" maxlength="50" placeholder="Пароль">
<input type="submit" name="log_in" id="login_but" value="Войти"><br/>


<a href="/restore" onClick="Page.Go(this.href); return false">Забыл пароль? </a>


</div>
</form>
 </div>
 </div> 
<div class=bara>
<div id=centru class=jom1><a href="#down"><img src="{theme}/images/home/jos.png" alt="Откройте для себя LIKAN desing, узнайте почему LIKAN desing особенный!"/><div id=text>Узнай больше </div>
</a>
</div> 
</div><div id=page>
<div id=centru><a name=down></a><center> 
<h1>Откройте для себя LIKAN desing, узнайте почему LIKAN desing особенный!</a></center>
     </div> 

<div id=centru><div class=browser></div></div>
<div class=part2><div id=centru>
<table cellpadding=5>
<tr><td valign=top><img src="{theme}/images/home/%2b.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network - My"/></td>
<td width=224><h2>My+</h2>На странице My+ ты найдешь последние новости от своих друзей или можешь отредактировать быстро и удобно материалы добавленные тобой на LIKAN desing.</td>
<td valign=top align=right width=107><img src="{theme}/images/home/space_talk.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network - SpaceTalk"/></td>
<td width=224><h2>SpaceTalk</h2>Space Talk поможет тебе общаться легко и просто со своими друзьями и близкими.</td>
<td valign=top align=right width=107><img src="{theme}/images/home/appsbox.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network - Apps"/></td>
<td width=224><h2>Appsbox</h2>  Развлекись и подними себе настроение листая приложения из appsbox.              </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding=5>
<tr>
<td valign=top><img src="{theme}/images/home/profile.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network - Люди"/></td>
<td width=224><h2>Люди</h2>
 Обрети новых друзей или найди быстро и удобно бывших одноклассников и друзей.</td>
<td valign=top align=right width=107><img src="{theme}/images/home/post.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network - Стенa"/></td>
<td width=224 valign=top><h2>Стенa</h2>
 Выражайся словами, видео или фотографиями. Покажи всем кто ты и чем увлекаешься. Поделись интересными и забавными случаями из своей жизни..</td>
<td valign=top align=right width=107><img src="{theme}/images/home/poze.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network - Фотографии"/></td>
<td width=224><h2>Фотографии</h2>
 Покажи незабываемые моменты. Поделись свежими фотографиями о последних путешествиях, прогулках, или других моментах проведенных в окружении близких людей.</td>
</tr>
</table> 


<div id=c12><a href="#contactForm" class=f_button title=""><div id=beta></div></a> </div> 


<div id=footer style="margin-top:-15px;"><div class=fereastra_lang style="left:10px;" ;>
<ul> 
<li><a href="lang/ro.html"><img src="../design.onspace.net/lang/Moldova_flag.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network - Romana"/>Romana</a></li>
<li><a href="lang/en.html"><img src="../design.onspace.net/lang/US_flag.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network - English (Beta-version)">English (Beta)</a></li>
<li><a href="lang/ru.html"><img src="../design.onspace.net/lang/Russia_flag.png" alt="LIKAN desing Social Network - Русский (Бета-версия)">Русский (Бета-версия)</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class=left>
&copy; 2014  </div>
</div>



</div> 

</div>      
</div>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Похвально, что в вопросе есть код. Плохо, что это не тот код, который мог бы помочь. Проблема скорее всего на сервере, а не в шаблоне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вероятность того, что у вас стоит настройка, чтоб при мобильном просмотре подгружается другой шаблон. Проверьте какой путь к шаблону при ошибке и удостовертесь что он есть по указанному пути

Comment: Где это можно посмотреть?

Comment: Если есть возможность, включите отображение ошибок в кмс или что там у вас и покажите скрин ошибки. По идее путь должен быть в ошибке